# Configuration for GitHub branch restrictions not on GitHub website

Tags: git, github, branch

I want to be able to restrict pushing to my master branch to certain collaborators.
There is supposedly a config item for this under branch protection - see github docs:
https://help.github.com/articles/enabling-branch-restrictions/

However when I go to the branch protection section there is no such config item. Does anyone know if you have to do anything special to enable it, or if its been taken out / yet to be introduced?

Answer (score 3):

This feature is only available for repos that belong to an **organization**.

This is stated in the last line of https://help.github.com/articles/about-protected-branches/

To use it: Move your repository from your private account to an "organization" (free to create), then you can specify people from the organization who have push rights to a given branch.

Organizations are in general a good idea for projects since they conserve the name even it the project owner changes.

Comment: Thanks Robin. Much appreciated.